# Which makes wcf service to RESTful service

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, rest, service

What needs to be changed to transition a `WCF Service` to a `RESTful Service`?
Can any one explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF supports a variety of different mechanisms for working with the resource representations that will be transmitted in the HTTP request/response messages. You can work directly with the raw request/response messages, by defining your method signatures in terms of System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, which allows you to use an XML or JSON API to process the messages.

Most developers, however, prefer to use a serialization engine that automatically moves between messages and .NET objects, such as the WCF `DataContractSerializer` (the default) or the `XmlSerializer` which allows more advanced structures not supported by `DataContractSerializer`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

When hosting your RESTful WCF services, there are two key components that you need to configure in order to enable the new “Web” behavior within the runtime. First, you need to expose an endpoint that uses the new binding for RESTful services – `WebHttpBinding`. Then, you need to configure the “Web” endpoint with the `WebHttpBehavior`.

```
<service name="BookmarkService">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="yourContractHere" />
</service>
```

The binding instructs WCF to not use SOAP anymore, but rather plain XML messages while the new behavior injects custom dispatching logic based on the `[WebGet]` and `[WebInvoke]` attributes and their corresponding `UriTemplates`.

```
[ServiceContract]
public partial class yourService
{
    ...
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "service/url/here?format=json")]
    [OperationContract]
    void yourMethod(string newValue)
    {
    …
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow 2 main [constraints](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm):

- uniform interface (using standards - like HTTP, IRI, URI template, hypermedia format, MIME types, etc... to describe contract between client and service)
- stateless (no server side session)